# Wordpress plugin is displaying the code query as html text

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the follow for my wordpress plugin:

```
<body>
    <h1>My example site</h1>

    <?php
      global $wpdb;
      //require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

      $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM red_reservacion;");

      foreach($posts as $row)
      {
      }

    ?>

</body>
```

That in my `.php` file.

But when the page is rendered in my browser displays:

[image]

I think the problem is the `greater than symbol`

Exist a way to fix it?

Comment: How is the url in the browser? Does it start with `FILE:///`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: @FirstOnethe `wp-load.php` is commented

Comment: Try changing `<?` to `<?php` in case short tags are disabled on your server. It's good to get in that habit anyways as short tags are deprecated.

Comment: Try with <?php instead of <?.

Comment: @Willian the same happens

Comment: What does the source code of the page look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposedly, your `short tags` is turned off so PHP does not recognize  just `<?` and by the way, You may also move all the PHP Code to the very Top of the Script to see if it helps... You might try this instead:

```
    <?php  //<== JUST ADD php AFTER <? 

        //require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
        // DO ALL THE PHP OPERATIONS OUTSIDE THE HTML BLOCK 
        // PERHAPS AT THE VERY TOP OF YOUR SCRIPT TO SEE IF IT HELPS...
        global $wpdb;
        $posts  = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM red_reservacion");
        $output = "";

        foreach($posts as $row){
            $output .= "<h2 class='h2-class'>{$row->post_title}</h2>" . PHP_EOL;
            $output .= "<div class='div-class'>{$row->post_content}</div>" . PHP_EOL;
            // CONTINUE BUILDING UP YOUR OUTPUT STRING HERE...
        }
    ?>

        <body>
            <h1>My example site</h1>
            <?php echo $output; ?>
        </body>
```

Comment: exactly the same issue

Comment: @MrMins        Then try moving all PHP Code outside the HTML Block and then see if it helps. The Code above was updated to illustrate that...